# Calling methods in views, that are defined in model. not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I had a lot of my logic in my views. I refactored this into methods in one of my models. They're being recognized, but not actually working as the IF doesn't change, as the database changes, to reflect a different method that should be called.

For example, my code was originally like this, with all the logic in the views.

```
@if($tenancy == null || $tenancy->accepted == 0 && $tenancy->request_sent != 1)
              <a href="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/create" class="btn btn-primary">Start Tenancy</a>
            @endif


          <!-- 
            If the user signed in isn't the owner of this profile.
            Do not show these buttons that control accept/reject/end
          -->

        @if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id)
          <!-- 
            If the request has been sent but hasn't been accepted.
            Give the option to accept and reject.
            This updates the values in DB.
          -->
          @if($tenancy != null && $tenancy->accepted == 0 && $tenancy->request_sent == 1)
            <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
            </form>
            <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/reject">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reject Request">
            </form>
              <!-- 
                If the request has been accepted.
                Show button to end the tenancy,
                and property details
              -->
          @elseif($tenancy != null && $tenancy->accepted == 1 && $tenancy->request_sent == 0)
            <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/end">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="End Tenancy">
            </form>
            <h5>Currently in Tenancy with {{$tenancy->landlord_name}}</h5>
            <h5>Your property is {{$tenancy->property_address}}</h5>
          @endif <!-- End of current user vs this user-->
        @endif <!-- Initial If-->
```

I then refactored it to this, using method names instead of logc. The methods are defined in my Tenancy controller.

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == $tenancy->tenant_id)
          <h1>You cannot add yourself</h1>
        @elseif($Tenancy->addTenancy())
          <a href="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/create" class="btn btn-primary">Start Tenancy</a>

    @endif

      <!-- 
        If the user signed in isn't the owner of this profile.
        Do not show these buttons that control accept/reject/end
      -->

    @if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id)
      <!-- 
        If the request has been sent but hasn't been accepted.
        Give the option to accept and reject.
        This updates the values in DB.
      -->
      @if($Tenancy->hasRequestPending())
        <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
        </form>
        <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/reject">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reject Request">
        </form>
          <!-- 
            If the request has been accepted.
            Show button to end the tenancy,
            and property details
          -->
      @elseif($Tenancy->inTenancy())
        <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/end">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="End Tenancy">
        </form>
        <h5>Currently in Tenancy with {{$Tenancy->landlord_name}}</h5>
        <h5>Your property is {{$Tenancy->property_address}}</h5>
      @endif <!-- End of current user vs this user-->
    @endif <!-- Initial If-->
```

This is the controller which renders the view above

```
  public function index($id){

   $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
   $users = Auth::user();
   $Tenancy = new Tenancy;
   $tenancy =  DB::table('tenancy')->first();

  return view('/pages/account/index', compact('user', 'users', 'Tenancy', 'tenancy'));
}
```

This is the Tenancy model where the methods are defined.

```
public function addTenancy()
{
    return $this->accepted == 0 && $this->request_sent == 0;
}

public function hasRequestPending()
{
    return $this->accepted == 0 && $this->request_sent == 1;
}

public function inTenancy()
{
    return $this->accepted == 1 && $this->request_sent == 0;
}
```

I can't see why the newly update view shouldn't be moving through the IF statement as the database changes. Any ideas?

Comment: @CaShiS perfect thanks very much. If you wan't to put this as a official ansewer, I'll accept as best answer.

Comment: You might want to change using both `Tenancy` and `tenancy` as variable names. Quite confusing.

Comment: @Robert. Yea good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont get eloquent model from database, but only get first row from table 'Tenancy' you should do something like this `$book = App\Book::first();` but first you must connect your model to database

Comment: Wouldn't this fail when the DB is empty?

Comment: @Robert this will return null, so you should check that variable to avoid unnecessery errors